# I got multiple entry schengen visa issued by Greece. Can I directly travel from India - Qatar - Romania or through schengen state

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, romania, greece

I got multiple entry schengen visa issued by Greece.. Can I directly travel from India - Qatar - Romania or should I have a stamping in schengen state?

Comment: I don't understand,. Romania is not currently part of the Schengen Area. How is having a Schengen visa relevant?

Comment: @brhans it is relevant because Romania allows Indian citizens (assuming OP is an Indian citizen) to enter with a valid Schengen visa, instead of having to apply for a separate visa.

Comment: Aah - that makes more sense now, and it wasn't me who -1'ed btw.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [website](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) of the Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs:

> Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The limited territorial validity visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The short-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The long-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The long-stay visa issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia;
> - The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state;
> - The residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus or Croatia
> - The long-term resident's EC residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European Union.

This website further adds that the number of entries or the validity period on the alternate visa should not have been exhausted. **As per this, it seems like your multiple entry Schengen visa is valid for entering Romania.** However, you may wish to confirm this by directly contacting your nearest Romanian foreign mission.